# ionic 4 Photo gallety on IOS-13 crash xcode 11.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic4, imagepicker

Ionic 4 image picker works perfectly for android devices, but does not work on IOS-13 devices.
getting error: "Error Returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts code=7 (null) "

Thank you

Comment: Same problem here, couldn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't mention purpose string of image gallery so please install plugin with purpose message.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker --variable PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"
```

Comment: I don't think so as the usage description is already defined at info.plist, probably the problem is because of the plugin uses UIView instead of WKWebview